# Function output not appearing in div

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

This is my first try at php. 
Trying to create a custom shortcode in wordpress to call custom metadata and put it inside a page content. It worked fine without the

```
function wpsl_staff() {
echo '<div class="staff">' .wpsl_get_staff(). '</div>';
function wpsl_get_staff() {
```

and with the shortcode being

```
add_shortcode( 'wpsl_staff', 'wpsl_get_staff' );
```

The output was correct but the output appeared at the top of the page above all other content and when I inspected in the browser it had no div or class id and just appeared as text. How do I wrap this in a div and give id so it sits properly on the content page (It should display between 2 images and under another shortcode) I have managed to give it a class id previously and get it to appear in a div but the output still appears at the top of the page above the images and other shortcode.

```
<?php
function wpsl_get_staff() {
global $post;
$queried_object = get_queried_object();{

$Manager = get_post_meta( $queried_object->ID, 'wpsl_Manager', true ); 
if  (!empty( $Manager )) return 'Manager : ' .$Manager . "<br>";
        else {}

$Assitant = get_post_meta( $queried_object->ID, 'wpsl_Assistant_Manager', true );
if  (!empty( $Assistant )) return 'Assistant Manager : ' .$assistant . "<br>";
        else {}

$Agent = get_post_meta( $queried_object->ID, 'wpsl_Agent', true ); 
if  (!empty( $Agent )) return 'Agent : ' .$Agent . "<br>";
        else {}
}
}

function wpsl_staff() {
echo '<div class="staff">' .wpsl_get_staff(). '</div>';

}
add_shortcode( 'wpsl_staff', 'wpsl_dio_staff' );
```

Thanks

- Toca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortcode functions are supposed to *return* the result, not directly output it.

```
function wpsl_staff() {
  return '<div class="staff">' .wpsl_get_staff(). '</div>';
}
```

---

Edit: You can only return one value from a function - so if your `wpsl_get_staff` is supposed to return data for all three types, then you need to assemble that data into a string variable first, and then return that at the end of the function - something like this:

```
function wpsl_get_staff() {
  global $post;
  $queried_object = get_queried_object();
  $output = '';

  $Manager = get_post_meta( $queried_object->ID, 'wpsl_Manager', true ); 
  if (!empty( $Manager )) {
    $output .= 'Manager : ' .$Manager . "<br>";
  }

  $Assitant = get_post_meta( $queried_object->ID, 'wpsl_Assistant_Manager', true );
  if (!empty( $Assistant )) {
    $output .= 'Assistant Manager : ' .$assistant . "<br>";
  }

  $Agent = get_post_meta( $queried_object->ID, 'wpsl_Agent', true ); 
  if (!empty( $Agent )) {
    $output .= 'Agent : ' .$Agent . "<br>";
  }

  return $output;
}
```

Comment: I understand that but when I use return there is no output on the page whereas echo shows the correct output (though the output does not appear in the correct place)

Comment: _“whereas echo shows the correct output (though the output does not appear in the correct place)”_ – yes, _because_ you are using echo, it shows in the wrong place. This code runs before the content is assembled, and therefor using echo the “timing” is just wrong. If you don’t get any output with return, then something else must be wrong. Start debugging by checking the HTML output generated.

Comment: Sorry should clarify. With using return like you showed me the manager output appears correctly on the page but the other 2 do not appear at all

Comment: You can only return one value from a function. If your `wpsl_get_staff` is supposed to return data for all three types, then you need to assemble that data into a string variable first, and then return that at the end of the function - see my edit please.

Comment: Wow thanks heaps. I have learned a lot. That works perfectly. Thanks again